# Windows 7 Enterprise to Windows 8 Upgrade

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I was thinking in upgrading my Windows 7 Enterprise to Windows 8 Enterprise in my laptop using the upgrade advisor, but my main doubt about this whole process is that if my currently valid Windows 7 Enterprise license will be invalidated?

This is an old laptop from a company that I've worked and that gracefully offered me the laptop, but I don't want to mess the licenses in that company.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M$ don't sell Win 8 Enterprise licenses to individual users, so that won't be an option for you. If you want to upgrade, you must either obtain a Windows 8 Enterprise image from your former employer, or use some registry hacking to upgrade to Windows 8 Pro.

Reference: [Windows 8 Upgrade Paths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203353.aspx)